# Decrypt a pcks8 private key file on windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, private-key, certutil

Is there any way on standard Windows Server (such as with certutil?) to decrypted a **pkcs8** pem encrypted private key?

i.e. What is the equivalent on windows of:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in key.enc -out key.pem
```

I tried looking through certutil doc for ages and cannot figure out any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Implentation of such tool is lacking inside Windows. I would suggest to just install the openssl library port for Windows inside your server. Your command would be the same after too.

Get it from there; [Win32/Win64 OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), or more source listed here; [Binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries).

Answer (score 0):

The 'official' Microsoft ecosystem way is to use a tool called PVK2PFX, which for some reason is only included in Microsoft SDK, and not in general windows releases.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).